# nested if conditions in python

Tags: python, json

I have a scenario where I need to check if the conditions in below json satisfy then do something.
here is my [json data](https://jsfiddle.net/7o80bc9r/)

here is my condition based on which I want to proceed:

Loop through the json and find value of `active` if `active` `true` then under the same parent array find under `cls` type if type is `alpha1` return the `eces` value (in this case 260551) `test_CHECK` value.

if after looping through json there is no value of `active` as true or value of `active` is true but in that same parent array under `cls` type is not alpha1 then print `not found`

Here is what I have tried but it seems to not go inside the loop.

```
for key in metadata:
    ev=key['eces']
    if key['active'] == 'true' and 'alpha1' in key['type']:
        print(ev, key['test_CHECK'])
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Also the challenge what I see is to verify that `type = alpha1` &  `active = true` under same object as it is looping the whole json.
any help would be great in order to how to proceed here.

Comment: You don't have to use `else` if you are not doing anything after the conditions.

Comment: @nakE ok but I need to get the result as found or not found

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use `else`, if the result found, it will print  `test_CHECK`, and if not just continue and then it will print `not found`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"cls": [
        {
            "c_id": 268897,
            "c_Address": {
                "test_CHECK": "passty",
                "testgama_URL": "https://testgama.com"
            },
            "address": "{world.com}",
            "name": "alpha",
            "type": "alpha1"
        }
    ]
```

Data is different in `cls` and ops questions, `test_CHECK` field is part of `c_Address` dict, so if we use that convention then we can find the required values using two for loops. One for loop will iterate on the outer list and another one is on `cls` list.

```
found = False
for di in d:
    if di.get('active', False):
        for cl in di.get('cls', []):
            if cl.get('type') == 'alpha1':
                print(di['eces'], cl['c_Address']['test_CHECK'])
                found = True

if not found:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, if there is a situation to store the result inside an array list, how do I achieve this. i mean I woul dbe running this inside a `for` loop then how can I store the results in a array list

Comment: for example here you can see the code https://jsfiddle.net/og09rz7u/1/ here, If I am doing something like this how should I append the output  the results of found =True in a array list.